# check whether Field[] contains a field with name XXX

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I got an array of `Field` of a class:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(FULL_CLASS_NAME);
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
```

I want to check whether the above `fileds` array contain a field named "**sumUp**". I am looking for a way which doesn't iterate through each element of `fields`. I tried:

```
String[] fieldNames = Arrays.copyOf(fields, fields.length, String.class);
boolean hasField = Arrays.asList(fieldNames).contains("sumUp"));
```

But compiler complains :

```
The method copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Field[], int, Class<String>)
```

I am wondering is it possible to fix the above error? if not, what could be the alternative way ?

Comment: *I am looking for a way which doesn't iterate through each element of fields* - Not possible because you have an array to work on and you need to check each element and compare it against "sumUp.

Comment: try `String[].class`.

Comment: You cannot use `copyOf` to convert a `Field` to a `String` and expect Java to magically know that you want the *name* to be extracted. And, btw. `List.contains` will also iterate over all elements, of course. (And so does `copyOf`…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get a field by name by `Class.getField(String name)`:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(FULL_CLASS_NAME);
try {
    Field f = clazz.getField("sumUp");
    System.out.println("sumUp field exists");
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
    System.out.println("sumUp field does not exist");
}
```

`getField()` searches for a `public` member field. If you also need to find `protected` and `private` fields too, you can use `Class.getDeclaredField(String name)`.